# JS how to replace elements before load the page (awesomium c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I'm using Awesomium on c# to load html page. Once Awesomium loads, then I execute the javascript to remove any other elements except the article that I needed.

The only problem is that it first shows the whole page and then remove less than 1 sec. There is a blink of change.

How can I not showing the page unless JS is completed? 
Currently I overlay a rectangle on top of the browser once OnLoadingFrameComplete then remove the overlay and display browser...

Thanks

Comment: How about this? you can simply add hidden class to that section of the page and once you JS is completed ,remove hidden class

Comment: @Matt.k Thnkas for the reply.
I pass URL to the Awesomium so there is no way that I can put hidden class....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass your URL to  `Awesomium` to load your `view (html)`. I am sure you have an access to your view (html) in your project directory, so you can add style of `display:none` to that section of the page in html part and then in your JS once your JS is completed show that section that is hidden.